# Git - xcode - single project multiple developer on LAN

Tags: ios, xcode, git, svn, git-svn

Using facility of git which is provided in the xcode I have setup one project. I got the understanding about the branch, commit etc from [This link](http://www.appcoda.com/git-source-control-in-xcode/)

Now I want to share this project with the other developer who can make change in this project from his own mac. Both the mac is in the same network. So can anyone please let me know how can I achieve it. If any link from where I can refer would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Xcode sets up is a local repository that is specific to you, and your Mac.

What you want is a central repository that developers can clone, so they can work in their own local copy of that repository.  Each developer can push their committed changes to the central (origin) repository. Others on the team can pull those changes to their local copy.

You can host this central repository in-house, by using OS X Server and Xcode Server.  Alternately, you can use a remote repository, as offered by sites such as [GitHub](https://github.com) and [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org).

This is a much cleaner solution, and offers far more flexibility and functionality than the problems that will arise trying to work from a single local repository on a shared drive.